# Computing the total hours worked

Tags: java

I can't figure out at the moment how am I going to calculate the total hours worked of an employee. Example:

```
Time-in: 07:00
Time-out: 05:00
```

I have two JTextField, that's where the user will input. How am I going to do it when he clicks my JButton Calculate Hours? Sorry guys, I know this is pretty easy but I am completely a novice, please help!

Comment: Please let us know what have you tried ?

Comment: I'd say, in the example he worked -2 hours. Can they stay more than one entire day? Which format does the Time have?

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526485/how-do-you-subtract-dates-in-java

Comment: Oh yeah right. I was thinking a 24-hour format... But what if he inputs a wrong time? How do I do exception handling?

Answer (score 1):

First, you must convert the input into two Date or Calendars.

Then check [Calculating difference in dates in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453388/calculating-difference-in-dates-in-java)