# Date substraction between String format and current time in Java

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I would like to know how could I achieve the below scenario. I have a date in String format ("mm/dd/yy HH:MM"):

```
String createdDate="01/14/15 08:11"
```

I need to get the time elapsed from the `createdDate`. If the time elapsed is greater than 4 hrs I have to perform some operation and if not I have to perform some other.

In short I need to get the difference of the created Date and currentDate/Time in Hrs and Mins.

Comment: Please provide code? what you have done so far?

Comment: Oh boy! `Urgent help required.`? How much are you offering to pay?

Comment: Google knows, really: http://goo.gl/quBtTm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating difference in dates in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453388/calculating-difference-in-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

```
  String format = ("mm/dd/yy HH:MM");
  String createdDate = "01/14/15 08:11";

  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
  LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(createdDate, formatter);

  Duration duration = Duration.ofHours(4);
```

If you want to use Java 8, it's a start of an answer.

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html for close this problem

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, M - in date format represents month, and m - minutes

Answer (score 0):

```
final long millisInHour = 3600000; //Number of milliseconds in an hour
final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm"); //Format to parse
final String createdDate = "01/14/15 08:11"; //The date to calculate elapsed time from

final long parsedMillis = format.parse(createdDate).getTime(); //Parse string and get the time in millis
final long currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); //Get the current time in millis
final long millisElapsed = parsedMillis - currentMillis; //Calculate elapsed millis

long hoursElapsed = millisElapsed / millisInHour; //Calculate the hours elapsed
```