# Period with hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: java, jsr310

I have need for an interval data type representing years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds. The first three (years, months, days) can be done with `Period` and the last three (hours, minutes, seconds) can be done with `Duration` however none of them seem to do both. Ideally I'd like to avoid having to implement a custom `TemporalAmount`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a code writing service.

Comment: Why code writing service? I have trouble understanding an API. "Ideally I'd like to avoid having to implement a custom TemporalAmount". So no, I'm not looking for code, I'm looking for understanding.

Comment: About the motivation of JSR-310-team to drop the originally planned support for mixed periods (containing months, days, time) see [this old threeten-issue](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten/issues/248) I suspect they feared the complexity and had not enough time before releasing Java-8. Well, writing such a class is indeed complex, see also the size of my [Duration-class](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/blob/master/core/src/main/java/net/time4j/Duration.java) - more than 5700 rows.  By the way, Joda-Time-Period is also such a class (and also complex).

Comment: A similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366154/how-to-handle-full-period-in-java-time) which is still open was posted some time earlier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a reason why there is no such type. There is no well defined time intervals such as "day", "month" or "year":

- day is not always 24 hours (depends on DST, timezone and leap seconds)
- every month has different number of days
- leap years have 366 days

Even if you implement a custom TemporalAmount there is high chance that your code will be incorrect in some cases. If you state your actual requirements you might get a better answer.

Comment: Yes there is, see the Period class.

Comment: Period only supports years, month and days units. It doesn't support hours, minutes, etc.

Comment: If you implement a TemporalAmount that supports both date and time units then would 25 hours be equivalent to 1 day and 1 hour? But this is not always true.

Comment: Yes I know that Period only supports years, month and days, that's what the question says. As I said, I would go for Period semantics, so 25 hours would be 25 hours.

Comment: What is the actual functionality that you want to implement (from the user point of view)?

Comment: I want to model the PostgreS [interval type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html)

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall Then you must read the documenation: »Internally interval values are stored as months, days, and seconds. This is done because the number of days in a month varies, and a day can have 23 or 25 hours if a daylight savings time adjustment is involved. The months and days fields are integers while the seconds field can store fractions.« So you need to create a class that consists of a Period and a Duration. You are safe with the years as PostgreSQL has a maximum of `178000000` years whereas Java Period's maximum is `2147483647` years. Why didn't you ask *that* in the beginning?

Answer (score 5):

The reason why there is no such class is that there are actually two different concepts of a time span. In Java, these two concepts are implemented in two different classes:

- a *fixed* number of (e.g.) seconds is a [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) in the Java world (think of a bag of seconds)
- a *variable* number of seconds in a larger time unit (like a month) which is called a [Period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html)

While a **duration** has always the same time length, the actual time length of a **period** depends on when and where it is applied. A period of one month can be 28, 29, 30 or 31 days - it's actual *duration* depends on the context. A period of one day may have 23, 24 or 25 hours (and more) when there's daylight savings in a given timezone.

Here's a small and likely incomplete list of factors that have an effect on the conversion of a period to a duration.

- minutes (leap seconds, ***this isn't implemented)
- days (daylight savings)
- months (28, 29, 30, 31 days)
- years (leap years)

That's why `Period` stores days, months and years seperately and `Duration` just seconds (and nano seconds). They do share the same time unit `DAY`, but a `Duration` day is considered to be 24h and is directly converted to 86,400 seconds.

So you need to define your application. Do you want a duration (fixed amount of seconds) or a period (something that happens once in a year, twice per month, every day at 2:00 am)?

Here's an example how they do compute different instants after a daylight savings change:

```
Duration oneDayDuration = Duration.ofDays(1);
Period oneDayPeriod = Period.ofDays(1);
ZonedDateTime beforeChange = Instant.parse("2015-10-25T00:00:00.00Z").atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
System.out.println(beforeChange);
System.out.println(oneDayDuration.addTo(beforeChange));
System.out.println(oneDayPeriod.addTo(beforeChange));
```

will print

```
2015-10-25T02:00+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
2015-10-26T01:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
2015-10-26T02:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
```

Comment: I would be willing to settle for the #addXXX semantics on Zoned/OffsetDateTime.