# Is there an xml timestamp format like the java timestamp?

Tags: java, xml, datetime, timestamp

My java timestamp has the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.ms
2016-01-08 15:16:44.554
```

I got it using the following method:

```
private String getCurrentTimeStamp() {

    Date date= new java.util.Date();        
    return((new Timestamp(date.getTime())).toString());

}
```

Is there a standardized xml date and Time format for timestamp? The `xs: dateTime` has the following format: `"YYYY-MM-DDThh: mm: SS"` And it is not taking into consideration milliseconds.

Comment: [dateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTime) does in fact allow milliseconds.  In fact, it permits [an infinite number of decimal places for seconds](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#nt-seFrag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the schema, you have to change your function

```
private String getCurrentTimeStamp() {
    Date date = new java.util.Date();        
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(date);
}
```

Comment: but I need the milliseconds part

Comment: @sabrina2020 try this: `return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(date);` be careful about the using of `.` instead of `:`

Answer (score 3):

XML itself does not define any timestamp formats.

XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition [incorporates ISO 8601 formats by reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#formatdetails). The dateTime format allows but does not require a decimal point followed by arbitrary fractions of a second. For example, 2016-01-08T15:16:44.554

Comment: FYI: [Summary of ISO 8601 standard formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 2):

In [XML Schema (XSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)), all formats of dates and times are well [defined](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_date.asp).

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supports these formats. See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Here are some examples:

```
// Dates in XML: YYYY-MM-DD
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.parse("2002-09-24");

// Dates with TimeZone in XML: YYYY-MM-DDZ
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.parse("2002-09-24Z");

// Dates with TimeZone in XML: YYYY-MM-DD-06:00 or YYYY-MM-DD+06:00
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.parse("2002-09-24-06:00");

// Times in XML: hh:mm:ss
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME.parse("09:00:00");
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME.parse("09:00:00.5");

// DateTimes in XML: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss (with an optional TimeZone)
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse("2002-05-30T09:00:00");
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse("2002-05-30T09:30:10.5");
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse("2002-05-30T09:00:00Z");
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse("2002-05-30T09:30:10.5-06:00");
```

Durations and Periods however are not perfectly compatible, because they are [split in Durations and Periods in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595133/period-with-hours-minutes-and-seconds/34596262#34596262). Here are however some examples:

```
Period.parse("P5Y");
Period.parse("P5Y2M10D");
Duration.parse("PT15H");
Duration.parse("-P10D");
```

Comment: FYI, these formats are defined by the ISO 8601 standard. The [Wikipedia page on ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is a must-read.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean the standart ISO for Date.

On this thread

[Convert Java Date...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099862/convert-java-date-into-xml-date-format-and-vice-versa)

See also:

[What is Jaxb and why would i use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607141/what-is-jaxb-and-why-would-i-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a format as part of XSD 1.1:

> The type xsd:dateTimeStamp represents a specific date
>   and time in the format CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss.

http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd11/t-xsd_dateTimeStamp.html