# Question about time stamp in relation to XML Tag

Tags: html, xml, tags

I'm asking this since I've asked around and can't find an answer when I tried to Google it online. I'm wanting to know what the +345172 number means?

<NC:DateStarted NC:parseType="Date">Wed Feb 09 11:28:00 GMT Standard Time 2005 +345172</NC:DateStarted>
<NC:DateEnded NC:parseType="Date">Wed Feb 09 11:28:00 GMT Standard Time 2005 +415273</NC:DateEnded>

Answer (score 0):

XML itself has no notion of time formats, and XSD uses [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Ask the author of the XML, or check any schema you might have for the XML.

### See also

- [Is there an xml timestamp format like the java timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34902963/290085)
- [How to locate an XML Schema (XSD) by namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25858335/290085)