# Why isn't time included in Java's Period class?

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time

In the Joda-Time library, the [`Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#Periods) class represents a period of time including years, months, days, hours, minutes, etc.

However, in Java Time API a [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class can only include a number of years, months and days.

Why can't I include a time in Java's `Period` object, and what is then the best way to express something like "2 days and 1 hour"?

I am aware of the `Duration` class, but it doesn't allow to specify "2 days and 1 hour" ; a duration of 49 hours may be different than "2 days and 1 hour" (DST, ...).

Comment: Wondered as well. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25760725/1743880

Comment: I found some interesting info regarding this in the [OpenJDK mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/threeten-dev/2013-September.txt) (look for the subject "ISO8601 durations and java.time").

Comment: This answer pretty much explains the reasons: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32369144/38896